# api-manager.bat --run in Wso2 api manager

Tags: cmd, wso2, wso2-api-manager

When i run this in cmd (bin directory)

```
 api-manager.bat --run
```

cmd goes to next line of cmd. I am not getting errors and it is not running also

I tried restarting my machine. I couldn't find any relevant scenarios

Comment: Did you install Java and set JAVA_HOME environment variable correctly?
Quick Start Guide: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/get-started/api-manager-quick-start-guide/#before-you-begin

Comment: Are you running this from within the `bin` folder inside the downloaded archive?

Comment: Found api manager.bat files has 0kb size.How it happened ??

Comment: i replaced api-manager bat file with new .how the size got reduced

Comment: Could be an issue with extracting the downloaded zip file.

Comment: it was working fine on yesterday today morning am facing am issue what i mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Try `api-manager.bat --start`. This is mentioned in doc[1].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/install/installing-the-product/running-the-api-m/#starting-the-api-m-server